# Points on hyperbola whose distance from line is minimum

Tags: inequality

> Let $P(x,y)$ and point on Hyperbola $3x^2-4y^2=36$, which is nearest to line $3x+2y=1.$ Then $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}(y-x)=$

What I try:

First we will find perpendicular distance of line $3x+2y-1=0$ from point $P(x,y),$ which is $\displaystyle d=\bigg|\frac{3x+2y-1}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2}}\bigg| =\bigg|\frac{3x+2y-1}{\sqrt{13}}\bigg|$

Now i am trying using Titu,s leema

$\displaystyle \frac{(3x)^2}{108}+\frac{(2y)^2}{-36}\geq \frac{(3x+2y)^2}{108-36}$

$\displaystyle (3x+2y)^2\leq 72\Longrightarrow (3x+2y)\leq 6\sqrt{2}$

And equality hold, when $\displaystyle \frac{(3x)}{108}=-\frac{(2y)}{36}\Longrightarrow x=-2y$

Put into $3x^2-4y^2=36\Longrightarrow x=\pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\displaystyle y=\mp 3\sqrt{2}$

But Here is my doubt is when we put $3x+2y=6\sqrt{2}$ in $\displaystyle d\leq \frac{6\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{13}}$

Which is maximum value of $d$, But here we have to obtain minimum of $d$

Please help me , Thanks

Comment: $\frac{(3x)^2}{108}+\frac{(2y)^2}{-36}\geq \frac{(3x+2y)^2}{108-36}$ is written as $-\frac{1}{24}(x+2y)^2 \ge 0$. So it should be reversed.

Comment: Thanks River Li means I have not  applied Inequality Rightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i am trying using Titu,s leema
> $\displaystyle \frac{(3x)^2}{108}+\frac{(2y)^2}{-36}\geq \frac{(3x+2y)^2}{108-36}$

This is not correct.

[Titu's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality) says that if $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}$ are real numbers with $\color{red}{b_1\gt 0,b_2\gt 0}$, then
$$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}\ge\frac{(a_1+a_2)^2}{b_1+b_2}$$
So, you cannot use Titu's lemma here.

You can use the following inequality :

If $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_2$ are real numbers with $\color{red}{0\gt b_2\gt -b_1}$, then
$$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}\color{red}{\le}\frac{(a_1+a_2)^2}{b_1+b_2}\tag1$$The equality is attained only when $a_1b_2 - a_2b_1=0$.

*Proof for $(1)$* :
$$\begin{align}&\frac{(a_1+a_2)^2}{b_1+b_2}-\bigg(\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}\bigg)\\\\&=\frac{b_1b_2(a_1+a_2)^2-a_1^2b_2(b_1+b_2)-a_2^2b_1(b_1+b_2)}{b_1b_2(b_1+b_2)}
\\\\&=\frac{-(a_1^2b_2^2-2a_1a_2b_1b_2+a_2^2b_1^2)}{b_1b_2(b_1+b_2)}
\\\\&=\frac{(a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2}{b_1(-b_2) (b_1 + b_2)}\ge 0.\ \blacksquare\end{align}$$

Using $(1)$, we have
$$ \frac{(3x)^2}{108}+\frac{(2y)^2}{-36}\color{red}{\le} \frac{(3x+2y)^2}{108-36}$$

So, we have
$$(3x+2y)^2\color{red}{\ge} 72 \implies |3x+2y|\ge 6\sqrt{2}$$

I think you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

We already  have that $(3x+2y)^2\geq 72$, that is $|3x+2y|\geq 6\sqrt{2}$,
and the equality holds, for instance, when $x=-2y$. Then
$36=3x^2-4y^2=2x^2$, so $x=\pm 3\sqrt{2}$, and $y=\mp\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
Thus the minimum of $d=\bigg|\frac{3x+2y-1}{\sqrt{13}}\bigg|$ is attained
when $3x+2y=6$, that is when $x=3\sqrt{2}$ and $y=-\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
Then $\sqrt{2}(y-x)=-9$.

Comment: Thanks Alex , But I have got $(3x+2y)^2\leq 72$ and you have written $(3x+2y)^2\geq 72.$ please explain me.

Comment: @jacky River Li [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4762934/points-on-hyperbola-whose-distance-from-line-is-minimum/4764034?noredirect=1#comment10114103_4762934) that the inequality $(3x+2y)^2\le 72$ should be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for a conic $S(x,y)=0$, tangent at point $P(x_1,y_1)$ is obtained by $T(x_1,y_1)=0$. Given the curve equation $S:3x^2-4y^2=36$, the tangent at $P(x_1,y_1)$ has equation $3xx_1 - 4yy_1=36$.

The tangents found by OP are $3x+2y=\pm 6\sqrt{2}$. The tangent with $+6\sqrt{2}$ is closer to $3x+2y=+1$ because both lie on same side of origin/center of the hyperbola.

Comparing the two equations of the tangent,
$$\frac{3x_1}{3}=\frac{-4y_1}{2}=\frac{36}{6\sqrt{2}} \quad \text{gives} \quad (x_1,y_1) = \Big(3\sqrt{2},\frac{-3\sqrt{2}}{2} \Big)$$
Hence $\sqrt{2}(y_1-x_1) = -9$

---

**Remark :** If hyperbola equation is $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, then a tangent of slope $m$ has equation $y=mx\pm \sqrt{a^2m^2-b^2}$. This result can be used to write down tangent at $P(x_1,y_1)$ without appealing to inequalities, although using inequalities is also a great approach! (The tangent at $P$ has same slope/is parallel to the given line.)